# wordpress get_option returning false

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have wordpress plugin which register settings like:

```
register_settings("myplugin_settings","myplugin_option1");
```

and on plugin activation it's adding options like:

```
add_option("myplugin_option1","");
```

Then if I update option, like:

```
update_option("myplugin_option1","something else");
```

and later try to get it from database:

```
$myoption = get_option("myplugin_option1");
```

get_option() returns false, even option exist and value is updated.

I know that value is updated and option exist because when I run query to get option I am getting the value:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = "myplugin_option1";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

This returns me value: "something else"

For example this code:

```
 $option = get_option("myplugin_option1");
 if(false == $option){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = "myplugin_option1"';
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
 }
```

After this code is executed, $result will contain value:

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
      (
        [option_id] => 11752
        [option_name] => myplugin_option1
        [option_value] => something else
        [autoload] => yes
      )
)
```

So option exist and has value but get_option() is returning false.

I have this problem only with 3 options and only on one site where my plugin is installed. Does anyone has some idea why get_option() returns false even option is in database and has value "something else".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this was that those three options with which I had problems was somehow cached twice in wp cache.

So one options was cached twice, and update_options() was always updating one of these two and get_option() was always getting the another one cached with empty value.

Not sure how this happened, but clearing cache resolved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

you should include the file `wp-blog-header.php` in any external file to be able to use Wordpress functions. That file is in your wordpress root folder.

Comment: It's included, and wordpress functions are working fine. I have issue just with 3 option, for all other it is working fine. I am getting options in one loop and just those fails.